# If $P$ is a prime ideal of an integral domain $D$, then is $D$ equal to its localization at $P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I refer to [this article](http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/aaol/rings2.html) on the localization of integral domains.

Let $D$ be an integral domain, and $P$ a prime ideal of $D$. $$D_P=\{ab^{-1}\mid a\in D,b\notin P\}$$

Let us suppose $P\subset D$. This means that $1\notin P$ (if $1\in P$, then $P=D$). We can thus show that $D\subseteq D_P$. The reason for that being keep $b^{-1}=1$. Then every element of $D$ is present in $D_P$.

Obviously, $D_P\subseteq D$. Does this imply that $D_P=D$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need to *suppose* that $P\subset D$ and $1\notin P$ - that's part of the definition of "prime ideal".

Comment: Why is it obvious that $D_P\subseteq D$? Consider $D=\mathbb Z$ and $P=2\mathbb Z$. What is $D_P$ then?

Comment: @ZevChonoles- I just meant to state $P\neq D$. An integral domain, like the principal ideal $(3)$ I suppose, can be a prime ideal. So $P=D$ is a possibility.

Comment: @Ayush: No, it isn't - [take a look at the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_commutative_rings) for instance.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews- I figured $D_p$ contains elements of the form $ab^{-1}$, where $a,b\in D$. All elements of this form are $\in D$. Hence $D_p\subseteq D$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles- Ok I stand corrected. Thanks! Before this I had only read that $P$ is a prime ideal if $ab\in P\Rightarrow a\in P$ or/and $b\in P$.

Comment: @Ayush: So, you would claim that everything of the form
$$\frac{a}{b}$$
where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$... ?

Comment: @ZevChonoles- I really have no idea why I was thinking of $D$ as a field. Now I suppose I understand the concept better. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the definition of $D_P$. $D_P$ is defined inside the field of fractions of $D$, so $D_P$ is hardly ever a subset of $D$.

In other words, $b$ does not need to be a unit of $D$ in the definition of $D_P$.

For example, if $D=\mathbb Z$ and $P=2\mathbb Z$, then $D_P$ is a subring of the rational numbers, namely:

$$D_P=\mathbb Z_{(2)} = \left\{\frac{a}b\in\mathbb Q: a,b\in\mathbb Z, \,b\not\in 2\mathbb Z\right\}$$

For example, $\frac{1}{3}\in D_P$ and $\frac{1}{3}\not\in D$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews- Thank you for your answer!